# Parsing Email Content in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I receive an e-mail each day that contains instructions for a number of newsletters that I write. I want to parse the content of the email to pull out the useful parts and store them in tuples.

Here is an example of what the content of the email looks like:

---

"An opening sentence with no useful information.

(XXX 1-111)

http://the_link_for_the_resource.com

(YYY 2-222)

http://the_link_for_the_second_resource.com

...

another useless sentence"

---

In this example, "XXX" = mailing list, "1-111" = segment

I want the information to be stored in tuples - (mailing_list,segment,url)

What's the best way to go about doing this?

### EDIT:

I wanted to determine whether parsing the exact content of the message would be doable before writing something to retrieve it from the server. So to start hacking away I wrote a quick script using the email module and an email file. Here's the code:

mail_file = open("new_board_mail.eml", "r")
    mail_message = email.message_from_file(mail_file)
    payload = mail_message.get_payload(decode=True)
    charset = mail_message.get_content_charset('iso-8859-1')
    mail_content = payload.decode(charset)

My understanding is that this code results in `mail_content` containing the Unicode string of the message's content. How would I go about parsing the content from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using python, I'd recommend the [imaplib](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html) module to connect to your mailbox, search for the particular email (assume it's coming from a certain address or has an identifiable subject), and then parse the contents.